# Changing SKU in amazon android app

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, skus

I have made an android app for amazon with in-app feature. Now I need to make my app live. My question is do I need to change any SKU string or so before uploading my app online? While testing my app, I had added a json file and an Sku string in my code, what do I replace them with?

```
Set<String>skuList = new HashSet<String>(1);
skuList.add(getResources().getString(R.string.consumable_sku));
PurchasingManager.initiateItemDataRequest(skuList);
```

Also, while initiating Purchase Response this skuString is being used.

```
PurchasingManager.initiatePurchaseRequest(skuString);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change it or not. When you define your product in the Amazon developer portal you will have the ability to define the IAP items for the app.   For each IAP item you have to define multiple properties one of which is the sku.  What matters is that the sku string in the portal match the request you make from the app.  Other properties include price, description, title, and various associated images.